# setCellValueFactory for TreeTableColumn

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I was using `TableView` and this `setCellValueFactory` for `TableColumn` was ok:

```
tc_number.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> new SimpleStringProperty(cellData.getValue().getDocNumber()));
```

Now, I've changed my table to `TreeTableView`, and I can't `setCellValueFactory` for `TreeTableColumn`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some manipulations I'm done. Sorry for question

```
tc_number.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> new SimpleStringProperty(cellData.getValue().getValue().getDocNumber()));
```